# ./bin/hadoop jar appears :in the thread when the "main" Java. Lang. Classnotfoundexception: org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount2

Tags: java, hadoop

I put the hadoop source wordcount.Java copied to my own created directory, compile passed and generate a JAR and passed to./bin/hadoop. Then I  modified wordcount.Java  and saved as a wordcount2.java in my own directory and compile passed,generate a JAR file but when run with ./bin/hadoop jar. It throws me below error.

```
in the thread when the "main" Java. Lang. Classnotfoundexception: org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount2,
```

This is how i ran the hadoop job

```
./usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar ./usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/playground/wordcount2.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.wordcount2 ./usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/input ./usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop/output
```

This is my codes:

```
package org.apache.hadoop.examples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCount2 {

  public static class TokenizerMapper 
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),"       \t\n\r\f,.:;?![]'");
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer 
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, 
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      if (sum > 4) context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf,     args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> [<in>...] <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount2.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,
      new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If yes, did you set main class name for jar properly as WordCount2?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!I am not using eclipse.in fact,i don't use any IDE,I just using the ubuntu terminal to do these.And the main class name for jar was automatically as WordCount2.This is how i generated the jar:                                     usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/javac -classthpath ...  -d usr/local/hadoop/playground/classes usr/local/hadoop/playground/src/WordCount2.java                              and   jar -cvf playground/WordCount2.jar playground/classes/*